# Epilog not working

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

When I run the following code

```
Plot[{y1[x], y1'[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}},
 GridLines -> {Automatic, {1/2}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"],
 PlotLabel -> "u''+0.25 u'+u=0",
Epilog -> {
   {PointSize[Large], Blue, 
    Point[{{0, y1[0]}, {Pi, y1[Pi]}, {2 Pi, y1[2 Pi]}}]},
   {PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point[{{0, y1'[0]}, {Pi, y1'[Pi]}, {2 Pi, y1'[2 Pi]}}]}
   },
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

I get the error message "Coordinate {0, {1.25}} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form." and "Coordinate {0, {0.5}} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."

Why won't my points show up on my Plot?

My `y1` is

```
y1[x_] = y[x] /. 
  DSolve[{y''[x] + 0.25 y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1/2, y'[0] == 5/4},
    y[x], x]
```

Could this be the source of my problem?

Comment: To find the source of the problem, break down your code to small pieces, and try to isolate the one causing trouble.  The error message suggests that you should try to evaluate `{0, y1[0]}` on its own.

Comment: Use Szabolic's suggestion.  I the return value is {0,{1.25}}, then your function is returning a list of one element.  You could use First to remove take only the first element of that list, or Flatten to turn {0,{1.25}} to {0,1.25}

Answer (score 2):

The built in functions Solve, NSolve, DSolve, etc. return a list of solutions, even if there is only one.  If you are sure that you want only a single solution you could use

```
y1[x_] = First[y[x] /. DSolve[{y''[x] + 0.25 y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1/2, y'[0] == 5/4}, y[x], x]]
```

Then evaluating y1[x] will yield a single value

The plot below was produced by your code.  Please check for syntax errors.
[image]

Comment: It's actually supposed to be u instead of y and t instead of x, but whe I run it, I get the error message,    equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {u[t]+0.25u'[t]==0,u[0]==1/2,True}               Why do I get this error? @JJM

Comment: @Wyatt.  The code in the solution above works fine giving `0.5 E^(-0.125 x) (2.64575 sin(0.992157 x)+1. cos(0.992157 x))` and y1[0]=0.5;  Please edit your question to show the changed function.

Comment: That is the answer I am getting also, but when I try to plot it the points for 0, Pi, and 2 Pi will not show up

Comment: Had to add First into my equation. Thank you!